# Equidistribution of the partition function

Tags: nt.number-theory

Experiments with the [partition](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Partition_(number_theory)) function $p(n)$ (for $n = 1, \dotsc, 100000$) seem to indicate that $p(n)$ is uniformly distributed modulo $q$ for every small prime $q.$ Is this known? Is it a special case of some general conjecture?

**EDIT**
As pointed out by him whose name cannot be pronounced in the comments, the above is not quite true:

For $q=5,$ the density of $0$ is twice as high as that of other residues (which are equally likely).

For $q=7,$ all nonzero residues are equally likely, but $0$ is more than twice as likely as the others.

For $q=11,$ the residue $0$ is exactly twice as likely as the others (all of which are equally likely).

Comment: I believe this depends on the prime. For example, with $q=5,7$ or $11$ frequency of $0$ is much higher than that of other residues. True, these primes are special because of the Ramanujan congruences; but then, there are also (more complicated) congruences modulo other primes too, so there might be more subtle frequency variations for them.

Comment: See Section 5.3 of Ono's book ``The web of modularity" for a discussion of this problem (until 2003).

Comment: Is "მამუკა ჯიბლაძე" really unpronounceable? Pasting into google translate gives "Mamuka Jibladze" from language "Georgian" which is what I've been going by ...

Comment: @BurnsBA Yes, I am aware of that.

Comment: Further numerical experiments are reported in Calkin, Neil; Davis, Jimena; James, Kevin; Perez, Elizabeth; Swannack, Charles; Computing the integer partition function.  Math. Comp. 76 (2007), no. 259, 1619–1638. MR2299791 (2007m:05022)

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

I believe this is not known. Ahlgren and Boylan proved in 2003 that $p(n)$ hits every mod $q$ residue class infinitely often, assuming $q\neq 3$ is a prime. They also gave a lower density estimate for $q\geq 5$, but this is too weak to imply actual positive lower density (except for the zero residue class).

Comment: Ahlgren, Scott; Boylan, Matthew Arithmetic properties of the partition function. Invent. Math. 153 (2003), no. 3, 487–502. MR2000466